# How can I determine why docker isn't running on CentOS?

Tags: centos, docker

I'm running CentOS and installed Docker using their [convenience script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-using-the-convenience-script).  Docker isn't starting though, it isn't available to me and says "inactive (dead)".  **How can I find out what the cause of this is?**

```
$ service docker status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: systemctl start docker; journalctl -xn will show the log of what's going on.

Comment: @DanilaLadner It says `No journal files were found`

Comment: check if syslog running and systemd-journald

Comment: Is your CentOS itself in a container? Docker can't be run inside another container (without a lot of hammering and arm-twisting).

Comment: What if you try to run it by hand... `sudo dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 0):

Use journalctl and filter by the docker service unit

```
journalctl -u docker.service
```